# kotlin-server Open API Generator generate with jakarta

Tags: kotlin, openapi-generator

I am using kotlin-server generator to generate my dto's and interfaces, with the latest quarkus platform update I need this tool to generate my classes using jakarta instead of javax. I see they made a patch for kotlin-spring generator with `useSpringBoot3` config option but nothing for the kotlin-server generator as far as I can see.

Am I missing something or is there a workaround for this?